# How can I change the text values in Google Data Studio?

Tags: case, looker-studio

I have a field called `duration_type` that can have the values below and I want to show them in my graphs  as the `expected_values` field:

| duration_type | expected_values |
| --- | --- |
| weekly | Week |
| monthly | Month |
| annual | Year |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a new `expected_values` field and create the [`CASE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020724) statement:

```
CASE
  WHEN duration_type = "weekly" THEN "Week"
  WHEN duration_type = "monthly" THEN "Month"
  WHEN duration_type = "annual" THEN "Year"
END
```